# Idempotents and cyclic codes

Tags: abstract-algebra, coding-theory

Let $C_1 = \langle e_1(x) \rangle$, $C_2 = \langle e_2(x) \rangle$ cyclic codes, where $e_1(x)$ and $e_2(x)$ are idempotents.

I know what cyclic codes and idempotents are, but why can one deduce the following: $C_1 \subset C_2  \Leftrightarrow  e_1(x) e_2(x) = e_1(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $C_1 \subset C_2$, then note that $e_1 \in C_1 \in C_2$. Hence $e_1 e_2 = e_2 e_1  = e_1$ because $e_1$ is an idempotent for $C_1$, and we can interpret $e_2$ as an element of $C_1$

For the other direction, if $e_1 e_2 = e_1$, then let $x \in C_1$. Now, $x = e_1 x = e_1 e_2 x = e_2 (e_1 x) = e_2 x$. Hence, $x = e_2 x$, and therefore $x \in C_2$.

Comment: Thanks for this really fast answer! What about $C_1 \cap C_2 = <e_1(x) e_2(x)> $ ?  Why does this hold true?

Comment: This is from the properties of ideals. If $I = \langle x \rangle$, $J = \langle y \rangle$, then $I \cap J = \langle lcm(x, y) \rangle$ in a principal ideal domain. You need to do some work to show that $lcm(e_1, e_2) = e_1e_2$ but that's the idea

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are talking about an idempotent $e=e(x)\in F[x]/(x^n-1)$.  The fact you are speaking of is actually true for idempotents in any commutative ring with identity.

Suppose $e,f$ are two idempotents in a commutative ring $R$.

Then it is elementary to show that $(e)\cap (1-e)=\{0\}$ and $(f)\cap (1-f)=\{0\}$.

Now if $(e)\subseteq (f)$, then $e-ef=e(1-f)\in (f)\cap (1-f)=\{0\}$. Therefore $e=ef$.

In the other direction, suppose $e=ef$: then clearly $e\in (f)$ and $(e)\subseteq (f)$.